# How to copy Range and past to last row

Tags: excel, vba, range, finance

I have a user input transaction information (Name, Amount, Date) in cells E33:G33.

User clicks button and the transaction is recorded in the last row +1 used in a Transaction history list starting on E46:G46.

So far my code doesnt work.

i want simply:
-copy range (E33:G33)
-find last row used in column E
-go one row lower
-past the copied range

Cant find a working answer, please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
Sub test()
Dim e&: e = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Range("E" & e & ":G" & e).Value = [E33:G33].Value 'past only values
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test2()
Dim e&: e = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
[E33:G33].Copy Range("E" & e & ":G" & e) 'past with cells format
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test3()
Dim e&: e = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
[E33:G33].Copy
Range("E" & e & ":G" & e).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll 'past with cells format
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test4()
Dim e&: e = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row + 1
[E33:G33].Copy
Range("E" & e & ":G" & e).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'past only values
End Sub
```

---

also:

`[E33:G33]` can be replaced by:

`Range("E33:G33")`

or

`Cells(Cells(33,"E"),Cells(33,"G"))`

or

`Cells(Cells(33,5),Cells(33,7))`